# ftpDownloadFile function is not available. Only on Android 10

Tags: android, ftp

I'm trying to download the apk file on the file server via ftp communication.
The file is downloaded normally from an Android 13 mobile device, but when tested with an Android-based PDA device called the MC2200, the APK file is not downloaded. For your information, it's Android 10 (API 29).

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                String downloadFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath();
                File pdaFolder = new File(downloadFolderPath);

                File files[] = pdaFolder.listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("file: " + files[i]);
                }

                boolean status = false;
                status = connectFTP.ftpConnect("192.168.5.2", "pda", "login1323", 21);
                if (status == true) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection Success");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed");
                }

                int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1;

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
                }


                cVersion = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
                System.out.println(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
                System.out.println(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);


                for (String fileName : connectFTP.ftpGetFileList("/PDA")) {
                    if (fileName.endsWith(".apk")) {
                        serverApkVersion = fileName.replaceAll("^\\(File\\)\\s*", "");
                        String localFilePath = downloadFolderPath + "/" + serverApkVersion;

                        if (!cVersion.equals(serverApkVersion.replace(".apk", ""))) {
                            System.out.println(connectFTP.ftpGetFileList("/PDA").length);
                            for(String a: connectFTP.ftpGetFileList("/PDA")) {
                                System.out.println(a);
                            }
                            System.out.println(serverApkVersion);
                            if (connectFTP.ftpDownloadFile("/PDA/" + serverApkVersion, localFilePath)) {

                            } else {
                System.out.println("failed");
                            }


                        }
                    }
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        customProgressDialog.dismiss();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, downloadFolderPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
```

On Android 10 devices, FTP CONNECT is normal, and the file list is also output normally. However, when using the ftpDownloadFile() function, it falls into the catch statement.

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(desFilePath);
The problem seems to occur in the above part.

Is this a problem caused by Android version difference,
I don't see what the problem is.

I'll leave the code below.

Comment: What is e.getMessage() at catch?

Comment: A READ permission does not help if you wanna WRITE a file.